# Is there a Cantor set $C$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ so the graph of every continuous function $[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ intersects $C$?

Tags: real-analysis, gn.general-topology

Consider the Cantor ternary set on the real line with the usual topology and define a *Cantor set* to be any topological space $C$ homeomorphic to the Cantor ternary set.

The idea is to construct a Cantor set $C$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ such that for every continuous function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ we have $C\cap\operatorname{Graph}(f)\neq\emptyset$, where $\operatorname{Graph}(f) = \{(x,f(x)):x\in[0,1]\}$.

Does the result generalize to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $n\ge 3$?

That is, for every positive integer $k$, let $I^{k}$ denote the product $[0,1]\overbrace{\times\cdots\times}^{k\rm\ times}[0,1]$. We seek to find a Cantor set $C$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that for every continuous function $f:I^{n-1}\rightarrow I^{n-1}$ we have $C\cap\operatorname{Graph}(f)\neq\emptyset$.

A related question can be found at *[Is there a cantor set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}-\{0\}$ which intersects every ray from the origin?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480171/is-there-a-cantor-set-in-mathbbrn-0-which-intersects-every-ray-from)*.

Comment: I think so. Something sort of like Antoine's necklace. $C=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty C_n$ where $C_n$ is the union of a finite number of disjoint closed S-shaped regions of diameter $\lt\varepsilon_n$, which are sort of "linked" into a sort of "chain" which is impassable to the graph of a function. If $C_1\supset C_2\supset\cdots$ and $\varepsilon_n\to0$ then $C$ is a Cantor set, and if the graph of a function $f$ has nonempty intersection with each $C_n$ then it has nonempty intersection with $C$. But I'm not up to making this rigorous, so this is just a comment.

Comment: Avoiding every ray is kind of trivial to ensure. The basic fact is to start from a Cantor $K$ and a continuous surjection $p:K\to S$, where $S$ is, say, the $(n-1)$-sphere, and consider the image of $K$ in $K\times S$ by $\mathrm{id}\times p$. This is a subset of $K\times S$, homeomorphic to $K$, projecting onto $S$. Since $K$ embeds into the reals, you get this using spherical coordinates (a Cantor intersecting every ray).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Following Will Brian's comments [1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/416982/is-there-a-cantor-set-c-in-mathbbr2-so-the-graph-of-every-continuous-f#comment1070172_417003) [2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/416982/is-there-a-cantor-set-c-in-mathbbr2-so-the-graph-of-every-continuous-f#comment1070173_417003), here is a graphical "proof" that the graph of every continuous function from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$ intersects my Cantor set whose original description is retained below.

Here are the first three steps $C_1$, $C_2$, $C_3$ of a construction that starts with the diagonal line from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$, and then in each step replaces the previous stage with two copies of it, scaled by $\frac{1}{2}$ horizontally and $\frac{2}{3}$ vertically:

[image: Picture of first step of iteration]

[image: Picture of second step of iteration]

[image: Picture of third step of iteration]

and here is $C_7$:

[image: Picture of seventh step of iteration]

So: starting with any continuous function $f: [0,1] \to [0,1]$, let $x_1$ be a point where its graph intersects $C_1$, $x_2$ a point where its graph intersects $C_2$, etc. That these intersections exist is visually obvious and not hard to prove rigorously. Any cluster point of this sequence will be a point of intersection between the graph of $f$ and my Cantor set.

---

Original post: I think there is such a Cantor set, and here is my proposal:

[image: Picture of proposed Cantor set]

The first few points are $(0,0)$, $(1,1)$, $(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3})$, $(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{2}{3})$, then we have $(\frac{1}{4}, \frac{2}{9})$, $(\frac{1}{4},\frac{4}{9})$, $(\frac{3}{4}, \frac{5}{9})$, $(\frac{3}{4}, \frac{7}{9})$, etc. Hopefully that explains the pattern. There is a homeomorphism from the usual Cantor set to this set which takes the middle-third endpoints to the points I started to list above.

I don't have any good ideas about how to prove that the graph of every continuous function intersects this, but I can't see how it could be avoided.

Comment: Does this set intersect the graph of $t\mapsto 1-t$?

Comment: To explain the pattern in a more rigorous though less clear way, let $(a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots) \in \{0,1 \}^{\infty}$. Then we plot the point $\left( \sum a_i/2^i,\ \sum a_i 2^i/3^{i+1} \right)$.

Comment: Nik, here is an idea for proving your example works. Write your Cantor space as the intersection of an infinite decreasing sequence $K_0 \supseteq K_1 \supseteq K_2 \dots$ of closed sets. $K_0$ can be the whole square. $K_1$ should look like two thick strips of positive slope, with a gap between them. $K_2$ should be 4 thick strips, even slopier, with one pair contained in each of the strips from $K_1$, etc. The graph of every continuous function meets $K_1$, because any path from the left-hand side to the right-hand side of the square has to snake between the two strips, and therefore . . .

Comment: cannot be functional. Similarly, you can argue that the graph of every continuous function meets $K_2$, and $K_3$, etc. So now fix some particular $f$. The graph of $f$ is compact, and so the sets $\mathrm{Graph}(f) \cap K_n$ form a decreasing sequence of compact sets. So their intersection is nonempty.

Comment: Wait, here's a much simpler idea for a proof. Let $f$ be a continuous function $[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$. We're going to choose an infinite decreasing sequence of intervals in the domain. Let $I_0 = [0,1]$. To choose $I_1$, look at $f(1/2)$: if $f(1/2) \leq 1/3$, then choose $I_1 = [0,1/2]$, if $f(1/2) \geq 2/3$, then choose $I_1 = [1/2,1]$, and if $1/3 < f(1/2) < 2/3$, then choose $I_1$ to be either $[0,1/2]$ or $[1/2,1]$ (it doesn't matter which). Supposing $I_1 = [0,1/2]$, choose $I_2 = [0,1/4]$ if $f(1/4) \leq 1/9$, choose $I_2 = [1/4,1/2]$ if $f(1/4) \geq 2/9$, and . . .

Comment: if $1/9 < f(1/4) < 2/9$ then choose $I_2$ to be either $[0,1/4]$ or $[1/4,1/2]$. If $I_0 = [1/2]$ instead, choose $I_1$ by looking at $f(3/4)$, and whether it is $\leq 7/9$ or $\geq 8/9$. Continue on in this way, and in the end, take $x = \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N}I_n$. Then $(x,f(x))$ is in your Cantor space.

Comment: @WillBrian wow! I think you're right.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Yeah, I already deleted the comment with a similar counterexample in mind.

Comment: So this is the graph of a function $\varphi(x)$ such that for any continuous $f$ there is an $x$ with $f(x)=\varphi(x)$. Moreover $\varphi$ seems to be continuous at all points except dyadic rationals (having at the latter jumps inversely proportional to their 2-adic valuations). Spectacular.

Comment: @Victor it was a counterexample to "Baire class 1", not "continuous".

Comment: @NikWeaver I've added pictures of your example at the [end of my own answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/417046/14094).

Comment: @YCor nice, thank you.

Answer (score 8):

Here's one simple other example of such a Cantor subset.

First, the theoretical side. In the closed unit square $[0,1]^2$, define a decreasing sequence of "simple" closed subsets $K_n$ (with complement $U_n$), and define $K=\bigcap_n K_n$. The conditions we can to ensure is that (a) $K$ is totally disconnected (b) $K$ meets the graph of every continuous map (written "graph" below).

A trivial but essential remark is that (b) holds if and only if no $U_n$ contains a graph. (Indeed, by compactness, if $U=\bigcup U_n$ contains a graph, then this graph is contained in $U_n$ for some $n$.) As regards (a), the condition to ensure is that the sup $r_n$ of diameters of connected components of $K_n$ tends to zero. (I don't insist on $K$ being Cantor because it's a trivial issue, which can always be ensured by enlarging it, e.g., replacing isolated points with small Cantor subsets.)

The interest is that while $K$ is a bit mysterious, the individual $U_n$ are meant to be easy to understand.

---

Now for the example. Each $U_n$ will be blue and $K_n$ white. Each $K_n$ will be a finite union of horizontal squares tilted by $45$ degrees, then intersected with $[0,1]$.

The basic construction is as follows: start from a square, cut it into $5\times 5$ squares and fill the 9 ones as follows:

[image: basic step]

Next, fill the 16 remaining $5$-times-smaller white squares in the same fashion, but in the orthogonal direction. Next, do the same with the $25$-times-smaller white squares, again in the original direction. Eventually tilt everything by 45 degrees.

At each step, this defines $U_1\subset U_2\subset U_3$...
The pictures are as follows, showing, for $i=1,2,3$, $U_i$ (blue), $K_i$ (white):

[image: 1st step]
[image: 2nd step]
[image: 3rd step]

(at the bounding square, the white part should be understood as the closure of the inner white part — it was written as a blue line only for readibility)

It can easily be checked that the sup of diameter of components of $K_n$ tends exponentially to zero. Next, $U_n$ contains no graph for any $n$. The point is that in $U_n$, the smallest $\Pi$-shaped paths (those in $U_n-U_{n-1}$) can't be used for travelling "to the right". Hence showing that $U_n$ contains no graph can be checked by induction. Of course details would be a little cumbersome to be written in Bourbaki-style, but this is quite visible from the picture, even for a non-mathematician.

---

Edit: here are pictures of subsets $U_n$ (blue color) for [Nik Weaver's example](https://mathoverflow.net/a/417003/14094), after 4 steps and after 11 steps:

[image: NW: 4 steps]

(the increasing slopes are $(4/3)^n$, while the apparently decreasing slopes are actually vertical segments)

[image: NW: 11 steps]

More precisely, define functions $f_i$ as in Nik's example, where $f_i$ has slope $(4/3)^i$ at each continuity point: $f_0(x)=x$, $f_1(x)=(4/3)x$ for $x<1/2$ and $=(4/3)x+(2/3)$ for $x>1/2$, etc. Note that $f_i$ is defined on the set $C$ of dyadic expansions, rather than on $[0,1]$ where it bi-valued at some dyadic numbers. Thus the $f_n$, viewed as continuous function on $C$, converge uniformly to a function $f$ and $f(C)$ is the desired Cantor set. We have $\|f_{n+1}-f_n\|_{\infty}\le \frac16(2/3)^n$, so $\|f_n-f\|_\infty\le \frac12(2/3)^n$. Thus I defined $U_n$ as the set of $(x,y)$ such that $|y-f_n(x)|>\frac12(2/3)^n$ (properly speaking this is ill-defined for for the few points at which $f_n$ is discontinous, in which case I mean that $\max(|y-f_n(x^+)|,|y-f_n(x^-)|)>\frac12(2/3)^n$).

---

PS pictures written with SageMath.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect not.

Fix $C$. Then its complement in $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ is open and path-connected, and so we can find a path $\gamma$ in this complement with $\gamma(0)_x=0$ and $\gamma(1)_x=1$. Moreover, we may take this path to be smooth by Whitney approximation. Consequently, $\gamma$ will have a vertical tangent line at only finitely many points. Applying the implicit function theorem, we get a smooth function $f$ defined on $[0,1]\setminus\{a_1,\dotsc,a_n\}$ (for some finite collection of $x$-values) whose graph avoids $C$.

I would guess that one can modify $f$ to get a function violating the criterion, possibly by repeating the process inductively in a neighborhood of each point with some condition guaranteeing the regularity of the limit, such as bounding the variation. However, I can't think of an argument right now.

Comment: I suspect the answer for at least the case $n=2$ is yes. Incidentally, I found a somewhat related question: Is there a cantor set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}−{0}$ which intersects every ray from the origin? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480171/is-there-a-cantor-set-in-mathbbrn-0-which-intersects-every-ray-from?rq=1

Comment: To be clear, in this construction we start with $\gamma:t\mapsto(\gamma_x(t),\gamma_y(t))$, right? So the singularities of $f$ are jumps?

Comment: @PierrePC Yes, that's right. That's another benefit of smoothness.

Comment: Vertical tangent is not the only problem. The curve might go back and forth in $x$ direction all the time so that the first attempt at your "function" takes many values at a given $x$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Switching directions will make the tangent line vertical at the switching point.

Comment: Yes, of course. But your sketch sounds like you are only modifying your curve near those points. That is not enough, when you have pieces lying above each other.

Comment: @ChristianRemling I've cut out any "repeated" bits. There won't be any pieces lying above each other, as I've removed the extras. That's why the function is only continuous off those points.